# Toad pattern in game of life

Tags: java, javascript, jakarta-ee, design-patterns, conways-game-of-life

I was trying to solve the Game of life problem for a test. Rules of that game are:

Any live cell with fewer than two live neighbors dies, as if caused by under-population.
Any live cell with two or three live neighbors’ lives on to the next generation.
Any live cell with more than three live neighbors dies, as if by overcrowding.
Any dead cell with exactly three live neighbors becomes a live cell, as if by reproduction.

I tested my work on various patterns like Block, Boat, Blinker and Toad pattern shown below.
But my code is not giving expected output for toad pattern as shown...although its working fine for every other pattern.

I am getting this output for TOAD:

```
X--X
X---
--X-
```

I checked various websites and they also showing the same output as below, but if we apply the rule, the cell in the 2nd row and last column cannot be alive.

> So can anyone please tell me which is the right output? I have to be
>   sure as it is for my test...

Thanks..

```
**Expected Output**

1.  Block Pattern
Input
X X
X X 
Output
X X
X X

2.  Boat Pattern
Input 
X X -
X - X
- X -
Output 
X X -
X - X
- X -

3.  Blinker Pattern
Input
- X -
- X -
- X - 
Output 
- - -
X X X
- - -

4. Toad Pattern
Input
- X X X
X X X -
- - X -
Output
X - - X
X - - X
- X - -
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your output from your described input for TOAD matches the rules you've stated.  The stated expected output doesn't match the rules.

It's not clear you have a problem in your program, but in your interpretation of TOAD, as noted by veredesmarald.

I'll also note that you defined input/expected-output for TOAD as follows:

```
Input
- X X X
X X X -
- - X -
Output
X - - X
X - - X
- X - -
```

And that if I move the line "Output" up one line the result matches the standard/expected definition of TOAD input/output:

```
Input
- X X X
X X X -
Output  // swapped with line below
- - X -
X - - X
X - - X
- X - -
```

It appears something simply got lost in translation, and your program may be fine.

Comment: hello I have a doubt regarding the input for game of life, can you please check the post given and answer if possible. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12191404/game-of-life-input-for-toad-pattern

Answer (score 3):

All the examples of the toad pattern I found via google look like this:

State 1:

```
- - - -
- x x x
x x x -
- - - -
```

State 2:

```
- - x -
x - - x
x - - x
- x - -
```

These two states oscillate like so:

[image: Animated example from Wikipedia]

Your input appears to be missing the top row and also has an extra live cell in the bottom row. As a side note, the "bloat" pattern you mentioned is actually called "boat", because it looks like an overhead view of a small boat.

See:

- [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway%27s_Game_of_Life#Examples_of_patterns)
- [Wonders of Math](http://www.math.com/students/wonders/life/life.html/)

Comment: So why is TOAD called TOAD? It doesn't really look like one to me.

Comment: @AdriaanKoster that's life :-/

Comment: Ah, so it's all just a game to you? (-;

Comment: @AdriaanKoster FWIW, I did some digging around and couldn't find anything. [LifeWiki](http://conwaylife.com/wiki/Toad) points out _"Toads often appear in large, complex patterns because of their ability to eat things when paired together"_ so perhaps the name comes from the fact that toads will eat most anything that fits in their mouths? Other than that I guess you would have to ask Simon Norton, who initially discovered the pattern and chose the name.

Comment: hello I have a doubt regarding the input for game of life, can you please check the post given and answer if possible. stackoverflow.com/questions/12191404/… – ManMohan Vyas

Comment: I'd say the name comes from toads inflating their throats. The first state *sort of* looks like a toad, the second state is, by some stretch of imagination, and inflated version of it, and then it goes back to the toad.