# Game of life - input for toad pattern

Tags: java, algorithm, conways-game-of-life

Can anyone please confirm for game of life:

if inputs

```
- - - -
- x x x
x x x -
- - - -
```

and

```
- x x x
x x x -
```

are similar . If yes. how ?? please explain.

For background on "game of life" problem .. please refer [Toad pattern in game of life](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11982217/toad-pattern-in-game-of-life) it is basically toad pattern input.

Comment: What is the *programming* related question?

Comment: @amit http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11982217/toad-pattern-in-game-of-life reffer this link for details :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a theoretical perspective, the two are identical, since the grid of cells is infinite, and all cells not denoted are assumed to be initially dead.

In practice, however, it depends on how your implementation of Life handles cells that are on the "edge" of the current grid. Depending on the implementation, there are three common ways of treating "edge" cells:

1. The grid is expanded to accommodate new cells coming to life outside the current grid (up to some limit, since there is only finite memory available).
2. Cells that would come to life outside the grid are ignored.
3. Cells on the edges are considered adjacent to the cells on the opposite edge (i.e. the grid wraps around).

If your implementation takes the second or third approach, the patterns will produce different results.

To avoid this confusion, patterns which stay contained within a certain space can be denoted including any necessary initially dead space, so as to avoid the edge problem all together. This is the approach that has been taken in the first pattern.

Comment: so if I include a dead row at the starting and end of input as well a column at the starting and the end of input , then all edge-input will be neigboured by a dead cell .. is this approch correct??

Comment: @ManMohan It's not really correct or incorrect, it's just convenient. Denoting a pattern which you know is constrained to an `m x n` area in an `m+2 x n+2` grid means that your pattern will always be rendered the same way, regardless of how the renderer handles edges.

Answer (score 0):

They're similar only in that the inputs *look* similar. The results are very different:

### Pattern 1

```
- - - -
- x x x
x x x -
- - - -

- - x -
x - - x
x - - x
- x - -

- - - -
- x x x
x x x -
- - - -
```

### Pattern 2

```
- x x x
x x x -

x - - x
x - - x

- - - -
- - - -
```